# What's the name of the font used in alphanet?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image]
What is the name of this font? I have checked in many sites but could not get a proper answer.
Might be this the same font used in oracle logo.

Answer (score 1):

Because this wordmark also reminded me of the [Oracle logo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Oracle_logo.svg), I searched for a rough free equivalent and landed on [Promethean](http://www.dafont.com/promethean.font?text=ALPHANET):

[image: Promethean screenshot]

Clearly different, but gets you in the same ballpark at least.

Note its license...free for personal use only.